# Delta Live Tables clusters termination

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-live-tables

I read in the documentation of dlt that "Because Delta Live Tables manages cluster auto-termination and reuse logic, the cluster auto-termination time cannot be overridden."

Is there a way to terminate my dlt cluster when the job is done, from a notebook or the configurations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Delay compute shutdown** configuration for terminating dlt cluster after pipeline execution.

```
{
"configuration": {
  "pipelines.clusterShutdown.delay": "60s"
}
}
```

Below is without above configuration, cluster is still running after pipeline run also.

[image]

Set the configuration in dlt settings.

[image]

Then start the pipeline and
click on **WAITING_FOR_RESOURCES** and select **Json**.

[image]

You will get cluster details use cluster id to see the state of it.

[image]

Output:

The cluster is terminated after delay of 2 minutes as i given that in configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to run your pipeline in the [Production mode](https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta-live-tables/settings.html#delay-compute-shutdown) - it will be then automatically terminated when job finishes:

> When **production mode** is enabled, the default value for `pipelines.clusterShutdown.delay` is **0 seconds**. When development mode is enabled, the default value is *2 hours*.